# Why is Firefox selenium webdriver not processing more then 20 tabs?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using the following script to upload my png images to a secret website:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import os

def select_image_for_tab(driver, image_file):
    # Find and click on "Browse for a file" button
    browse_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Browse for a file']")
    browse_button.click()

    # Wait for the file input to be visible and interactable
    time.sleep(0.5)

    # Handle the file upload dialog using Selenium
    file_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']")
    file_input.send_keys(image_file)

    # Wait for the file to be uploaded and the file selection dialog to close
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']")))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    image_files_directory = r"E:\Desktop\social\Output_folder\folder 20"

    # Prompt to focus on Firefox
    print("Please focus on Firefox. The script will start in 5 seconds...")
    time.sleep(5)

    # Set up the Firefox driver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    try:
        # Open the website in a new tab
        driver.get("UPLOAD_URL.com")

        # Wait for the website to load and the target element to be clickable
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='ms-Stack css-147']//div)[1]")))

        # Click on the target element
        target_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='ms-Stack css-147']//div)[1]")
        target_element.click()

        # Get a list of all PNG image files in the directory
        image_files = [f for f in os.listdir(image_files_directory) if f.lower().endswith('.png')]

        # Select image files for each tab
        for image_file in image_files:
            select_image_for_tab(driver, os.path.join(image_files_directory, image_file))
            time.sleep(0.5)  # Adjust this delay if needed

            # Open a new tab and load the website in it
            driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank');")
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
            driver.get("UPLOAD_URL.com")

            # Wait for the website to load in the new tab and the target element to be clickable
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='ms-Stack css-147']//div)[1]")))

            time.sleep(4)  # Additional wait time if needed

        print("File selection completed for all tabs.")
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", e)
    finally:
        # The script will not close the browser or any tabs after completion
        pass
```

But every time I have to divide my files into groups of 20.
Firefox is not processing more than 20 tabs. How can I bypass this limit in remoted Firefox?

**Note: Please don't ask about secret URL or UPLOAD_URL.com**

Comment: you might want to include an exception or a description of what happens/what should happen.  Could be resources... could be using an index to switch your windows handle... etc... but you shouldn't assume the window handle indexes are in order or that it has a handle yet... better to use webdriverwait with numberOfWindowsToBe​: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#numberOfWindowsToBe(int)  Get handles before opening new one, check numberOfWindows, then iterate through current handles and find the handle that is new.

Answer (score 1):

No need answer, I found solution.
I must set the `dom.popup_maximum` preference to 50 using `opts.set_preference("dom.popup_maximum", 50)`. Then I must use the `opts` when initializing the `webdriver.Firefox()` using `driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)`.
**This allows Firefox to handle up to 50 popup windows (tabs) at a time, which should allow you to process a larger number of images in your script without hitting the maximum tab limit.**